# Qt-QML JIT on Raspberry PI Rev. 1

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qml, jit

Me and my friend are working on a portable internet radio driven by a Raspberry PI B+ and a little touch screen. I am developing the interface with Qt-5.9 which I've cross compiled for the ARMv6 CPU of the PI. My interface is using QML, so when I launch my app, everythings working but the QML animations are lagging. 
Accordingly the console tells me that the QML JIT is not enabled (`JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.`), so I looked up on the given page about the V4 engine and after around two weeks of trying out, I found out that the problem is the missing possibility of using the Thumb-1 instruction set, which is needed by V4, and the HardFP configuration of the Raspbian Jessie running on the Pi. So now I think it would work if i get the cross-compiler to working with the Thumb-1 set. I tried a lot and in the end i got two problems.

1. When I use the `-mthumb` flag in the command line, i get this error: `sorry, unimplemented: Thumb-1 hard-float VFP ABI`. I need the Thumb-1, I can't change the Hard-Float implementation of the whole OS and there is no suitable compiler flag for ARMv6 to disable VFP.
2. When I use the `-mthumb-interwork` flag in the command line, the compilation works, but the executable doesn't change because of the ABI setting (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options)
   (`-mthumb-interwork: ... In AAPCS (the ABI) configurations this option is meaningless.`). I tried every possible ABI but none works and compiles a running program.

I've read about some patches for the RPi too, but they got included in the upstream Qt a long time ago.

I modified the compiler arguments a bit for trying out (file: QT/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi-g++/qmake.conf):

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS           += \
                      -mthumb \
                      -mfpu=vfp \
                      -mtune=arm1176jzf-s \
                      -march=armv6zk \
                      -mabi=aapcs-linux
```

(This configuration doesn't work)

I configured QT with the following arguments:

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip webengine -make libs -no-icu -tslib -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v
```

I hope you guys are smarter than me in solving those problems cause i think i tried everything possible to make the JIT working.

It would be bad if this problem is unsolvable, because Qt-QML is a very suitable GUI soulution for embedded devices like the PI, and six of eight RPis are running this old ARMv6 CPU.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know enough about your specific problem, but i propose this:

I recommend you to use Boot2Qt, which is a yocto-linux build and is designed for embedded hardware. With it you get a lightweight linux distro and all the Qt-Libraries.

You can conveniently setup your application to start on boot and it performs very well, even on slow hardware.
here is the documentation on building it:

http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-custom-embedded-linux-image.html

This url is about the commercial product but you can get the source in the repo below. Otherwise follow the instructions of the documentation.

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/yocto/meta-boot2qt.git
```

You are going to need a linux os for building. Ubuntu 16 and 18 worked well for me.

Boot2Qt is compatible with R-PI 1-3, Zero and many other devices. See the documentation for a more complete list.